# Rename the 'Shop' Breadcrumb and change the link in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, breadcrumbs

I tried using this code below to change the URL of the word "Shop" but it seems to do nothing:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_page_title', 'woo_shop_page_title');
function woo_shop_page_title( $page_title ) {
       if( 'Shop' == $page_title) {
              return "My new title";
       }
}
```

[image]

I don't want users to go to the main "Shop" page and setup many categories. 
Unfortunately I have not been able to find a way to remove or change the URL of that "Shop" breadcrumb. The [official docs](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/customise-the-woocommerce-breadcrumb/) only mention how to change the "Home" URL, not "Shop".

You're help is appreciated.

Comment: I think, the breadcrumbs goes from your theme, so should hook to some theme function

Answer (score 1):

To **rename** any breadcrumb item and **change its link**, use `woocommerce_get_breadcrumb` filter hook this way:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_breadcrumb', 'custom_get_breadcrumb', 20, 2 );
function custom_get_breadcrumb( $crumbs, $breadcrumb ){
    if( ! is_shop() ) return $crumbs; // Only shop page

    // The Crump item to target
    $target = __( 'Shop', 'woocommerce' );

    foreach($crumbs as $key => $crumb){
        if( $target === $crumb[0] ){
            // 1. Change name
            $crumbs[$key][0] = __( 'Name', 'woocommerce' );

            // 2. Change URL (you can also use get_permalink( $id ) with the post Id
            $crumbs[$key][1] = home_url( '/my-link/' );
        }
    }
    return $crumbs;
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme).* Tested and works.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not working. The site just gets stuck on loading. No errors on my console. Can it depend on the theme?

Comment: @viriato Sorry but this code works just fine and depend on your theme customizations (and also some plugins can make trouble ). I have just tested it again on storefront theme and woocommerce last version. It doesn't throw any error… So please, you can say next time when commenting that it's not working "with your theme"…

Answer (score 0):

Please check this code in on home replace Start chenag in woocommerce

function woocommerce_breadcrumb( $args = array() ) {
        $args = wp_parse_args( $args, apply_filters( 'woocommerce_breadcrumb_defaults', array(
            'delimiter'   => ' / ',
            'wrap_before' => '',
            'wrap_after'  => '',
            'before'      => '',
            'after'       => '',
            'home'        => _x( 'Home', 'breadcrumb', 'woocommerce' ),
        ) ) );

```
    $breadcrumbs = new WC_Breadcrumb();
    $args['home'] = "Start"; // home replace start set
    if ( ! empty( $args['home'] ) ) {
        $breadcrumbs->add_crumb( $args['home'], apply_filters( 'woocommerce_breadcrumb_home_url', home_url() ) );
    }

    $args['breadcrumb'] = $breadcrumbs->generate();
```

Answer (score -2):

The 'shop' breadcrumb is coming from you 'Shop' pages'. Simply change your shop page slug to whatever you want, or if it is another page altogether then in the woocommerce settings you set the shop page to your new page. The url will always be the page's slug.

Comment: Really not helpful answer. That is a very well known setting and there might be many reasons why one does not want to use that setting. Therefore, there might be many reasons why your suggested solution is a very unhelpful answer.